# How do I set a base object's defaults?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am new to JavaScript and trying to get my head around object constructors vs prototype when defining the base object's properties and methods with defaults.

```
// base object
function Animal (nameArg, typeArg) {
    this.name = nameArg,
    this.type= typeArg,
    this.sayHello = function() {
        console.log("Hello my name is", this.name, " and I am an ", this.type);
    }
}
// Setting defaults
Animal.prototype.name = "Anonymous";
Animal.prototype.type = "Animal";

//instantiating an animal WITHOUT any arguments passed in
var cat = new Animal; // I am getting undefined when I try to access properties like name

//instantiating an animal WITH argguments passed in
var lion = new Animal("Jimmy", "Lion"); // works as expected
```

Comment: You have set the base object defaults here.

Comment: So why do I get undefined when I try to access cat.name? (I am doing this in the browser console)

Comment: Why is sayHello not on the prototype? Is sayHello unique for each Animal instance? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What you're doing wrong

You're setting it to `undefined`: it's a value in itself.  You shouldn't be defining it at all for it to work:

```
// base object
function Animal (nameArg, typeArg) {
    if (nameArg) this.name = nameArg;
    if (typeArg) this.type = typeArg;
    // could be added to prototype, it's the same for each instance
    this.sayHello = function () { console.log("Hello my name is " + this.name + " and I am an " + this.type); }; // don't use commas here, use the + operator instead
}

// Setting defaults
Animal.prototype.name = "Anonymous";
Animal.prototype.type = "Animal";

var cat = new Animal(); // passing no arguments to constructor
cat.sayHello(); // now gives correct result ("Hello my name is Anonymous and I am an Animal")

//instantiating an animal WITH argguments passed in
var lion = new Animal("Jimmy", "Lion"); // always worked
```

#### Why this is the case

There's actually a difference between a variable set to undefined and a variable never defined, funnily enough - yet another of JavaScript's common quirks.  To tell the difference between an undefined variable and one never defined, take this example:

```
var foo = { x: undefined };
console.log('x' in foo); // true, x has been defined as "undefined"
console.log('y' in foo); // false, foo.y has never been defined
```

Arguments in JavaScript default to `undefined`, similar to when variables are initially defined without setting a value to them or being explicitly set to `undefined`:

```
function test(arg)
{   console.log(arg); // undefined
    console.log(doesNotExist); // ReferenceError: doesNotExist is not defined
}
test(); // run and see
```

By assigning to it, JavaScript keeps a record of it being assigned to, and therefore doesn't look up the prototype chain to see whether the property exists or not ([reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.2)).

Answer (score 2):

No need to use the prototype if you're instantiating the function. Also, I would *call* the `Animal` constructor by adding brackets afterwards:

```
// base object
function Animal (nameArg, typeArg) {
    this.name = nameArg || "Anonymous";
    this.type= typeArg || "Animal";
    this.sayHello = function() {
        console.log("Hello my name is", this.name, " and I am an ", this.type);
    };
}

//instantiating an animal WITHOUT any arguments passed in
var cat = new Animal(); // <-- note the brackets

//instantiating an animal WITH argguments passed in
var lion = new Animal("Jimmy", "Lion");
```

The reason your version of the code isn't working is because, despite the fact that you're not passing any arguments, the construction method of `Animal` is setting the original variables as `undefined`, overriding the prototype defaults.

Comment: side point: i was told that - strictly speaking - that I didn't need to add the brackets when calling the constructor with the "new"keyword if am not passing in any arguments but it was good to for readability. Is this correct?

Comment: @Andy I believe this may be true, as you're prepending `new` it assumes the intended use. But I wouldn't get into the habit of doing it personally. :-)

Comment: @Andy: it's just personal but if it _can_ expect an argument and you decide not to, I prefer to place the empty parentheses there.  Of course though, it's perfectly fine to do so (from a "doesn't give an error" point of view).

Answer (score 1):

```
function Animal (args) {
    if(typeof args === 'object') {
        this.name = 'nameArg' in args ? args.nameArg : default_value,
        this.type = 'typeArg' in args ? args.typeArg : default_value,
    }
    else
    {
        this.name = default_value;
        this.name = default_value;
    }
}

new Animal({});
new Animal({nameArg: 'hehe'});
new Animal({typeArg: 'hehe'});
new Animal({nameArg: 'hehe', typeArg: 'hehe'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your constructor to:

```
function Animal (nameArg, typeArg) {
    this.name = nameArg || this.name; // if nameArg is not defined take default instead
    this.type= typeArg || this.type; // if typeArg is not defined take default instead
    this.sayHello = function() {
        console.log("Hello my name is", this.name, " and I am an ", this.type);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var cat = new Animal();
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the defaults in the proper way, but you override them in your constructor. Try this:

```
function Animal (nameArg, typeArg) {
    if (nameArg != null) this.name = nameArg,
    if (typeArg != null) this.type = typeArg,
    this.sayHello = function() {
        console.log("Hello my name is", this.name, " and I am an ", this.type);
    }
}
```

Also, setting the sayHello method on the prototype is a big win, more than just using the prototype for defaults.

Answer (score 0):

`cat = new Animal()` is basically `cat = new Animal( undefined, undefined )`, and these arguments are used as `this.name` and `this.type`. To not overwrite defaults from prototype just check if the arguments were provided:

```
function Animal (nameArg, typeArg) {
    if(nameArg) this.name = nameArg;
    if(typeArg) this.type= typeArg;
    this.sayHello = function() {
        console.log("Hello my name is", this.name, " and I am an ", this.type);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K6Wu8/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `||` to set the default to the prototype values if undefined is passed in.

```
function Animal (nameArg, typeArg) {
    this.name = nameArg || this.name,
    this.type= typeArg || this.type,
    this.sayHello = function() {
        console.log("Hello my name is", this.name, " and I am an ", this.type);
    }
}
// Setting defaults
Animal.prototype.name = "Anonymous";
Animal.prototype.type = "Animal";

//instantiating an animal WITHOUT any arguments passed in
var cat = new Animal; // I am getting undefined when I try to access properties like name

//instantiating an animal WITH argguments passed in
var lion = new Animal("Jimmy", "Lion"); // works as expected
```

Example Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/LwsRE/